# LAMP HTML/PHP can't load images

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a movie database and I have a Python script that downloads movie posters (and information) and stores them in a folder. For example, `/var/www/html/images`.

I also have a PHP file that displays a unique page for each movie, according to the ID. So for example there is a list page, the user clicks on a film and it goes to `localhost/movielist.php?id=3` etc.

So far, the movie information is displaying perfectly. However, the images won't load.

In my python script, I save the movie poster image as the movie's name, so say if I had Finding Nemo's poster, the file name would be `Finding Nemo.jpg`. It saves it fine and I can look at the image in a folder.

The problem is that the image won't display on my PHP page.

This is the PHP code in my file:

```
<?php

$username="root"; $password="12345"; $database="videos";

$con = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($con, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($con, "localhost", $username, $password, $database);

mysqli_select_db($database);

if(isset($_GET["id"])){
  $id = $_GET["id"];
} else {
  require("listFull.php");
}

$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, title, yr, genre, plot, rating FROM films WHERE id = " . $id);

$movItems = array("Title" => "title", "Year" => "yr", "Genre" => "genre", "Plot" => "plot", "Rating" => "rating");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $res )){

  foreach($movItems as $k => $el){
    echo "<h3>" . $k . "</h3>";
    echo "<p>" . $row[$el] . "</p>";
  }
  echo "<img src='/var/www/html/images/".$row['title'].".jpg'>";
}
?>
```

This gets the row/movie's information according to the ID of the page and displays it. The image's name in the image folder is the same as the movie name in the database.

How can I get my images to display?

Comment: Your `<img>` tag is missing a `<`

Comment: @Machavity Oops, I was testing to see the file names, so I forgot to change some of the pieces of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely to be with your image path, this should be relative to the web root directory, not the actual path on the web server. So for example if your web root directory is /var/www/html and your images are stored in /var/www/html/images then your image path should be:

```
echo "<img src='/images/".$row['title'].".jpg'>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the img tag. First of all, the tag is malformed, the `<`at the beginning is missing.

Secondly, you shouldn't use /var/www/html/ as your image path because that directories are visible only in localhost. If you want to make them public you have to provide the correct url like www.mysite.com/images/Finding%20Nemo.jpg.

Finally, pay attention at the files' name: in http requests you can use spaces and other special characters (in the example above I substituted the space with %20) so make sure to substitute them.